# Function editing an array which isn't passed into said function

Tags: c#, arrays

```
        int[] sortedArrayAsc;
        int[] sortedArrayDesc;
        switch (sortChoice)
        {
            case "1":
                sortedArrayAsc = Sorts.Bubblesort(array, "asc");
                sortedArrayDesc = Sorts.Bubblesort(array, "desc");
                break;
            case "2":
                sortedArrayAsc = Sorts.InsertionSort(array, "asc");
                sortedArrayDesc = Sorts.InsertionSort(array, "desc");
                break;
            case "3":
                sortedArrayAsc = Sorts.MergeSort(array, "asc");
                sortedArrayDesc = Sorts.MergeSort(array, "desc");
                break;
            case "4":
                sortedArrayAsc = Sorts.PrintTree(array, "asc");
                sortedArrayDesc = Sorts.PrintTree(array, "desc");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Merge sort by default...");
                sortedArrayAsc = Sorts.MergeSort(array, "asc");
                sortedArrayDesc = Sorts.MergeSort(array, "desc");
                break;
        }
```

This is a simple switch case. Two arrays are declared , completely independent of each other. When I run the Merge and Treesort, the sortedArrayAsc and sortedArrayDesc are as they should be. However when I run the bubble and insertion. sortedArrayAsc returns what it should initially, but when the descending sort is done, the sortedArrayAsc changes for some reason. Here are some screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Code for bubblesort:
[image]

Comment: It seems, that something is wrong with `Bubblesort` and `InsertionSort` methods, please share its code

Comment: I'm betting those two are modifying the original array

Comment: I suspect your bubble sort and insertion sort modify the *existing* array instead of creating a *new* array. I suspect your two variables end up referring to the same array. We can't really tell without seeing those methods though. How comfortable are you in terms of reference types and value types? It may be worth reading https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: Shouldn't the two arrays be independent though? I return the sorted array, which shouldn't modify the existing array that isn't passed in.

Answer (score 1):

The way I fixed this was changing the line

```
int[] sortedArray = x;
```

into

```
int[] sortedArray = (int[])x.Clone();
```

Comment: Exactly. The reason is that in `C#` arrays are always reference types and the assignment `y = x` between two arrays, only copies the reference (the memory location) and not the actual data. The solution is to make a copy, which you did with `.Clone()` which internally calls `Array.Copy()`.

Comment: Thanks ja. I knew that arrays were reference but the fact that a function that returns int[] was also a reference to the existing array was interested. They must have been all looking at the same memory location! Thanks :)

Comment: Side note: shorter version is *Linq* `int[] sortedArray = x.ToArray();`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I'll use that